# Gaussian elimination questions

Tags: c++

I'm trying to walk through a C++ program for Gaussian elimination (all of it is below the snippet. I have gotten pretty far in it but i get stuck at this part:

```
 MatA[i][j] = MatA[i][j]/Divisor;
    }

    MatB[i] = MatB[i]/Divisor;

    if (i+1 < n) {
        for (k=i+1; k<n; k++) {
            Factor = MatA[k][i];
            MatA[k][i] = 0.0;
            for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
                MatA[k][j] = MatA[k][j] - Factor * MatA[i][j];
            }
            MatB[k] = MatB[k] - Factor * MatB[i]
```

Gaussian Elimination:

```
int main(){
int i, j, k, n;
float MatA[100][100], MatB[100], X[100];
float Divisor, Factor, sum;
cin >> n;

for(i=0; i< n; i++) {
    for(j=0; j < n; j++) {
        cin >> MatA[i][j];
    }
}

for(i=0; i< n; i++) {
    cin >> MatB[i];
}

for (i=0; i< n; i++) {
    Divisor = MatA[i][i];
    MatA[i][i] = 1.0;

    for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
        MatA[i][j] = MatA[i][j]/Divisor;
    }

    MatB[i] = MatB[i]/Divisor;

    if (i+1 < n) {
        for (k=i+1; k<n; k++) {
            Factor = MatA[k][i];
            MatA[k][i] = 0.0;
            for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
                MatA[k][j] = MatA[k][j] - Factor * MatA[i][j];
            }
            MatB[k] = MatB[k] - Factor * MatB[i];
        }
    }
}

X[n-1] = MatB[n-1];
for (i = n-2; i>=0; i--) {

    sum = 0.0;
    for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
        sum = sum + MatA[i][j] * X[j];
    }
    X[i] = MatB[i] - sum;
}

for(i=0; i< n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cout << MatA[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << " " << MatB[i] << endl;
}
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    cout << "X[" << i << "] is: " ;
    cout << X[i] << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: this part: `MatA[k][j] = MatA[k][j] - Factor * MatA[i][j];
            }
            MatB[k] = MatB[k] - Factor * MatB[i] `

Comment: i dont know how you multiply a matrix. and then subtract

Comment: Are you unclear on the math or how the math is translated to C++?

Comment: i think translated.

Comment: The translation of the math to C++ code is as simple as it gets. I don't think it can be simplified any further.

Comment: ok then i dont get the math then

Comment: i just realized I was trying to do this without actual numbers in the matrixs i was trying to literally trying to multupke A[1][0] times A[2][0]. i didnt know that i needed to input float digits into them.  sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If this is for exercise, good. If this is for actual code, you might want to check the numerical instability issues of Gaussian elimination and consider other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the fact that you need to take into consideration zero or very small diagonal elements when performing Gaussian elimination...

Let's say you are at the first row.

`M[0][0]` is your pivot element. You are dividing each element of the first row by `M[0][0]`, which makes the value of `M[0][0]` equal to `1.0` and rest of the elements are computed. This is not a necessary step to perform Guussian elimination but you are doing this in your code. After the lines

```
for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
    MatA[i][j] = MatA[i][j]/Divisor;
}
```

are executed for `i = 0`, you have:

```
1.0  m12   ...  m1n
```

in the first row. The second row has not been processed yet. Let's say the second row looks like:

```
m21  m22   ...  m2n
```

The next step is making sure that the second row looks like:

```
0.0  m_new22   ...  m_new2n
```

To arrive at that state, you need to perform the following operations.

```
second row = second row - m21 * first row

m21_new = m21 - m21*m11  ==> 0.0 since m11 is 1.0.
m22_new = m22 - m21*m12
m23_new = m23 - m21*m13

...
m2j_new = m2j - m21*m1j
...

m2n_new = m2n - m21*m1n
```

The constant in these operation is `m21`, which is `Factor` in your code.

The line:

```
MatA[k][j] = MatA[k][j] - Factor * MatA[i][j];
```

is the code equivalent of:

```
m2j_new = m2j - m21*m1j
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out this site: http://euler.mcs.utulsa.edu/~class_diaz/cs2503/Spring99/lab7/node8.html

There is no easy way that read it and try to understand on your own.